# PHP extract just a specific number from a string

Tags: php, string, int

How is possible extract only the number after the last = symbol in a string like this:

```
/neuroscan/analysis/admin/listo_aoi_list.php?mastertable=listo_pages&masterkey1=11
```

the number could be `1,11,345,888888` etc, I would if possible get it into an int variable.

Thanks

Comment: you can get it by $_GET['masterkey1'] in your listo_aoi_list.php file

Comment: If this is url the you use `$_GET['masterkey1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$val = (explode("=",$url));
echo $val[1];
```

`$val[1]` to getting second value after explode text after "="

Answer (score 1):

Try

`$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$val = (explode("=",$url));
end($val);`

It will always return you the last value after "="